# Get the newest file based on timestamp in Java

Tags: java

I have a directory which contains files in the following format. The files are in a diretory called `/incoming/external/data`

```
ABC_20100806.csv
ABC_20100807.csv
ABC_20100808.csv
ABC_20100809.csv
ABC_20100810.csv
ABC_20100811.csv
ABC_20100812.csv
```

As you can see the filename of the file includes a timestamp. i.e. `[RANGE]_[YYYYMMDD].csv`

What i need to do is find out which of these files has the newest date using the timestamp on the filename not the system timestamp and store the filename in a variable and move it to another directory and move the rest to a different directory in java.

Comment: Looks like you should be able to sort those names lexically. What issue(s) are you having?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the filenames into an array using:

```
File directory = new File("/incoming/external/data");
String[] fileNames = directory.list(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String fileName) {
         return fileName.endsWith(".csv");
    }
});
```

And from there simply sort the array if your files always have the same prefix:

```
Arrays.sort(fileNames);
```

One way you can remove the prefix and suffix of each fileName to extract the date is:

```
int underline = fileName.indexOf("_");
int dot = fileName.indexOf(".");
String datePart = fileName.substring(underline, dot);
```

And then you can add that string to an array and sort (lexically).

If for some other reason you want to convert the dates into Java Dates, you can use:

```
SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmdd");
Date date = dt.parse(datepart);
```

And you'll have a Java date, which you can also sort in an array or list.